# Restore FULL Oracle DB from ORADATA after DISK fail

Tags: oracle, restore, files

my system DISK crashed and know I have to restore my oracle from ORADATA only.

CTL, DBF, REDO is okay because system was shutdown normally.

I installed new harddisks and new OS.
After that I installed Oracle 12.1 Standard Edition One with database.

Than I tried shutdown and restart with my old ORADATA (moveing DIR, like with Postgres).
It doesn't work. ;-(((

What is a good working way? ;-)

Thanks a lot.
Regards, Jan

Comment: What does the term 'ORADATA' refer to? What operating system are we dealing with?  We don't know what you have or what you  have done, But it's certain the recovery methods of other databases are not appropriate for oracle.

Comment: ORADATA is directory for instances and all oracle data files (DBF, CTL, REDO....LOG) on windows. OS is windows 10 professional. My old system crashed and I had to change my system disk. So all settings in "C:\Program Files", "C:\ProgramData" are lost.